# Collapsed Nav Bar overlaps page contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm a rank beginner so please forgive my code, i understand its pretty messy and needs to be cleaned. Ive tried to create a paralax type website, using two "slides", just by using 2 elements and styling them to have separate fixed backgrounds. Now my problem comes in the form of the bootstrap navbar i am using. When the navbar collapses, and i click the burger icon, it works, however the list covers my content on the second slide, instead of pushing the content further down the page, ive searched alot however im thinking the way i have created my HTML is the problem.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="slide1">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="RJAhome2.html">
                    <img class="logo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/PwCMx8gHG4ubuI13n0hSh1o6Ks8oucZ_14mnDI-wb58wneRKDlQY6_Ujuf87g61dNDLo8YXMzpY34v7jLnI6A4BfnDb0WOxzhrKycp0g">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="RJAhome2.html"><strong>HOME </strong><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="RJAabout.html"><strong>ABOUT US </strong></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><strong>THE ACADEMY </strong><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="RJAinstructors.html">THE INSTRUCTORS</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="RJAbjj.html">BJJ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="RJAjj.html">KENPO JIU JITSU</a></li>
                            <li><a href="RJAboxing.html">BOXING/KICKBOXING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="RJAmma.html">MMA</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="RJApricing.html">PRICING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="RJAphotos.html">PHOTOS & VIDEOS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="RJAtestimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="RJAschedule.html"><strong>SCHEDULE </strong></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><strong>ROGER'S BJJ </strong><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="RJAachievements.html">ACHIEVEMENTS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="RJAhistory.html">HISTORY</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="RJAcontact.html"><strong>CONTACT US </strong></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="headers">
        <h4>GOSPORT & FAREHAM'S HOME OF CHAMPIONS</h4>
        <h1><strong>ROGER'S BJJ ACADEMY</strong></h1>

        <button id="infobutton" class="btn btn-lg">VIEW OUR SCHEDULE</button>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="slide2">
<div class="contact">
<div>
  <a href="RJAhome.html"><img class="logo2" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/PwCMx8gHG4ubuI13n0hSh1o6Ks8oucZ_14mnDI-wb58wneRKDlQY6_Ujuf87g61dNDLo8YXMzpY34v7jLnI6A4BfnDb0WOxzhrKycp0g"></a>
</div>
ROGER'S BJJ ACADEMY <br> 
UNIT D18 HERITAGE BUSINESS PARK <br>
HERITAGE WAY GOSPORT <br>
HAMPSHIRE PO12 4BG <br>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/rogersbjj/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/128542971053416/rogers-jiujitsu-academy-the-tigers-lair-gym/"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    font-family: Rajdhani;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
  }


.dropdown-menu li, .dropdown-menu a {
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    margin:0px;
    color: white;
    background-color: white;


}

.logo {
    width: 7em;

}

.navbar {
    font-family: Rajdhani;
    border: 0px white solid;

}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 5.5em;

}
li a {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.collapsed {
    color: white;
}

#slide1 {
    background: url(dojo.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height:700px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;


}

#slide2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333333;
    height: 235px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 15px;

}

.headers {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 14em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-family: Rajdhani;
    font-weight: 1000px;

}

#infobutton {
    display: block;
    width: 10.5em;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin-top: 1em;

}

.contact {
    font-family: Rajdhani;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo2 {
    width: 7em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

The nav bar just overlaps anything on the second slide. how can i get it to push EVERY other elements down rather? thanks :D

Comment: Add this as fiddle or smt...

Comment: first time posting, im not sure what you mean as fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to re-create your code to see what it is you are trying to fix, so I apologise if this is not what you are looking for.

Using the bootstrap 'navbar-fixed-top' adds a z-index property, which is what is used to determine how far in front or behind your elements will be placed. As standard bootstrap 'navbar-fixed-top' is set to:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
top: 0;
z-index: 1030;
}
```

it will be placed on top of your other elements, which I assume have not has a z-index set. Also using

```
position: fixed;
```

keeps your element in place, normally leading to your other elements moving behind it unless set otherwise.

What I have done to fix, what I think is your problem, is:

*Removed:*

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
}
```

*Added:*

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
position: sticky;
}
.body-content {
position: relative;
}
```

The reason I have used position sticky, is by personal preference only. If your nav-bar is going to stay at the top of your page anyway, using sticky (I find) makes it easier to arrange your other elements relative to it. In other words, to stop it from laying on top, and it rather laying beside it until scrolling.

I hope this helps, this is my first ever answer so again apologies if it is not what you are looking for!

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not quite what i was looking for. i dont want the nav bar to stick to the top, im leaving the navbar without any extra classes to ensure that it is transparent.